# Repository Pattern MVC4 EF5

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, repository-pattern

Being fairly new to MVC4, ASP.NET and Entity Framework, I've been looking into the use of the repository and unit of work patterns, and I'd like to verify my understanding.

Am I right in thinking that the `DBContext` used within EF5 CodeFirst acts as a unit of work?

In this case, is there any point in implementing repositories?

Or should I use:

`Model - Repository - ViewModel - Controller - View`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the MVC Scaffolding project on CodePlex:

http://mvcscaffolding.codeplex.com/

Also, here's a walk-through that shows a little intro on how to use it:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/468777/Code-First-with-Entity-Framework-5-using-MVC4-and

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.

I understand how to implement the repository pattern and I understand MVC Scaffolding. I'm just curious whether there is any point in using the repository and unit of work pattern when the DBContext is acting as a unit of work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some ideas, why you don`t need to use UoF in your MVC project.

[UoW](http://www.hareville.com/2013/01/using-the-repository-pattern-with-entityframework-codefirst-mvc4/)